# inheritence class not compiling

Tags: java, inheritance

i am just playing around with code and learned about inheritance in class today, cant get this to compile and dont know what is wrong, just says that it can not find C in the line colorfeathers = c

```
public class Bird extends inheritance{

    private String colorFeathers;

    public Bird(String c, String n){
        super("Bird:" , n, 2, 0);
        colorFeathers = c;
    }

    public String GetColor(){return colorFeathers;}

    public void setColors(){colorFeathers = c;}

    public String toString(){             
        String hold = super.toString(); 
        hold += "color:" + colorFeathers;
        return hold;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `inheritance`? Is that a class you're extending?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the `public void setColors(){colorFeathers = c;}`
You are not passing in `c` as a string so the variable is unknown in the context of the `setColors method`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the parameter here

```
 public void setColors(String c){colorFeathers = c;}
```

assuming all other things in superclass are okay

Answer (score 0):

The `c` in this function

```
public Bird(String c, String n){
   super("Bird:" , n, 2, 0);
   colorFeathers = c;
}
```

Only exists in that function. Once the function is complete, `c` no longer exists. Therefore, this call to the `c` variable

```
public void setColors(){colorFeathers = c;}
```

Cannot work.

Perhaps you also mean for `setColors` to have a `c` parameter? Like this

```
public void setColors(String c){colorFeathers = c;}
```